# How to Convert Set (HashSet) to Array in Kotlin?

Tags: arrays, kotlin, set, hashset

I have set of String

```
 val set = HashSet<String>()
    set.add("a")
    set.add("b")
    set.add("c")
```

I need to convert it to array

```
val array = arrayOf("a", "b", "c")
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use extension function `toTypedArray` as follow

```
set.toTypedArray()
```

That function belongs to Kotlin Library

```
/**
 * Returns a *typed* array containing all of the elements of this collection.
 *
 * Allocates an array of runtime type `T` having its size equal to the size of this collection
 * and populates the array with the elements of this collection.
 * @sample samples.collections.Collections.Collections.collectionToTypedArray
 */
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
public actual inline fun <reified T> Collection<T>.toTypedArray(): Array<T> {
    @Suppress("PLATFORM_CLASS_MAPPED_TO_KOTLIN")
    val thisCollection = this as java.util.Collection<T>
    return thisCollection.toArray(arrayOfNulls<T>(0)) as Array<T>
}
```

Comment: That's the solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Convert Set (HashSet) to Array**

```
import java.util.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val set = HashSet<String>()
    set.add("a")
    set.add("b")
    set.add("c")

    val array = arrayOfNulls<String>(set.size)
    set.toArray(array)

    println("Array: ${Arrays.toString(array)}")

}
```

When you run the program, the output will be:

```
Array: [a, b, c]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply `val array = set.toArray()`

Comment: It not work fine: `Type mismatch. Required: Array<String> Found: Array<(out)Any!>!`

Comment: @AbnerEscócio I tried it in Intellij IDEA and it works fine. It is `Array<(out)Any>!` and there is no problem with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call

```
val array = set.toArray()
```

Tested with Kotlin 1.2.51.

Comment: It not work fine: Type mismatch. Required: Array<String> Found: Array<(out)Any!>!