# Kotlin - Is there a way to access the keys of a HashMap iteratively?

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to use a `HashMap` to create a `dataframe` object. The dataframe object does not allow an ArrayList of ArrayLists to be passed which is the format my data comes in, hence the HashMap.

My code scrapes an HTML table and so gets all the table headers in one ArrayList then each row in its own ArrayList. The issue is trying to change this to a HashMap is that I need to add each key as an empty ArrayList and then use that key iteratively to add values to its ArrayList.

My code is as follows

```
    private fun getData() {
        val doc = get_data()
        val table = doc.select(".table")
        val dataMap =  HashMap<String, ArrayList<*>>()

        table.select("thead").select("tr").forEach {row ->
            row.getElementsByTag("th").forEach { cell ->
                dataMap[cell.text()] = ArrayList<String>()
            }
            Log.d("EMPTY Map:", dataMap.toString())
        }
        // Get the table body cells
        var index = 0
        table.select("tbody").select("tr").forEach {row ->
            val key = dataMap.keys[index]  // Issue is here. I can not use an index position to get the key.
            index += 1
            row.getElementsByTag("td").forEach { cell ->
                dataMap[key].add(cell.text())
            }
        }
        val df = dataFrameOf(dataMap)
    }
```

I am stumped as kotlin does not appear to let me index the keys by number despite `.keys` returning a set. What do I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Convert Set (HashSet) to Array in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51369214/how-to-convert-set-hashset-to-array-in-kotlin)

Comment: No I am trying to convert an ArrayList to a HashSet

Comment: Just asking, but why do you want to transform this into columns of rows and not rows of columns? I believe data frames are generally organized into rows, but you do something different. I mean, wouldn't it make more sense to have a list of maps and not a map of lists?

Comment: I suggest you simply build an auxiliary Map of index to header (string) and get key from it

Comment: @gdomo Not even a map, but array or list.

Comment: @DavidFrick Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but you seem to want to index the the keys by a number.  I understand you're getting a hash set of arrays, but you can convert the set of keys you get back also into an array to iterate over them.

Comment: @possum, dataframe wants the data in a weird format

Comment: I figured it mostly out.